# Why Next-Auth provider disabled my Antd Style

Tags: next.js, antd, next-auth

i just implemented Next-Auth and Antd design for my NextJs 13
The struture of Root Layout like this

```
const RootLayout = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) => (
  <html lang="en">
    <body className={font.className}>
      <ConfigProvider theme={theme}> // This is for Antd
        <StyledComponentsRegistry>
          <NextAuthProvider> // This is for Next-Auth
            <MainLayout>{children}</MainLayout> // This is my MainLayout i created
          </NextAuthProvider>
        </StyledComponentsRegistry>
      </ConfigProvider>
    </body>
  </html>
);
```

And I created comopent called MainLayout the logic is: If Next-Auth is loading show the Loading component like this

```
const MainLayout = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  if (status === "loading")
    return (
      <div
        className="fixed z-50 h-screen inset-0 w-full flex justify-center items-center bg-gray-50"
      >
        <Spin indicator={<LoadingOutlined style={{ fontSize: 50 }} spin />} />
      </div>
    );
```

But after that, the Next-Auth loading UI is good but Antd Style missing some thing, my primary button does not worked, like this

[image: Missing Button primary color]